# Store file retrieved by HTTP GET

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, urllib3

I have an API I can retrieve files from. I do this using `urllib3` in `python`.

e.g.

```py
url = "https://example.com/api/files/13"
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
```

where the headers dict contain information for authentication.

When decoding all the data in the response, get the same result as I would expect. I verified this with the response in the network information terminal of my browser:

```py
load = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
data = load['data']
```

`data` is at this stage a long string containing characters and digits and looks, depending on the file, similar to `dG0seHJheSxtZWRQaG90b24uU04yMDE2LUlSMDA3LkltUmlfRGV0X3BvcyxtZWRQaG90b24uU04yMDE2LUlSMDA3LkltUmlfRGV0X3ZlbCxtZWRQaG90b24uU04yMDE2LUlSMDA3LkltUmlfRGV0X2FjYyxtZWRQaG90b24uU04yMDE2LUlSMDA3LkltUmlfUm5nX3BvcyxtZWRQaG90b24uU04yMDE2LUlSMDA3LkltUmlfUm5nX3ZlbCxtZWRQaG90b...`, continuing after the dots. But it is just a csv file.

The only challenge I face now is to store the data to the disc. What I tried so far was:

```py
with open(dst_file, 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(data)
```

Instead of the `outfile.write(...)` I also tried `shutil.copyfileobj(r, out_file)`, but does not work either.

I guess it depends on the representation of the data I have it present. I guess having it as a string is not really beneficial. But how to store it?

**EDIT:**
One thing that maybe have to be noted: The api url does not contain the file, so the call will be redirected. I tried it with another file from the web, here i did get the desired data immediately presented, when accessing `>> r.data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bit of a different one. I was not aware, how the data was encoded and that it even was (honestly, didn't expect a small csv to be encoded).

Using the retrieved data and decoding it with base64 solved the problem in this certain case.

```
import base64
...
data_str = base64.b64decode(load["data"])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using requests you should be able to add a `allow_redirects=True` flag which might do the trick. In urllib3 you can manipulate this behaviour by setting the amount of retries. I'm not to familiar with this so I'll just leave a link to it.

Just CTRL+F for redirect!

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html